# Passing array of int to webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, asmx

I have an `$.ajax` call to a .NET web service, which in turn leverages a function in a DAL down to the Entity Framework. I think this will work, but the trouble is with passing the array of artist IDs.  I have tried all sorts of crazy conversions from string arrays to int arrays, I've used Linq `.Select` and none of it works. I always get `Cannot convert object of type System.String to type System.Int32[]` or similar. I understand the error, I just don't know how to fix it.

This is my jQuery:

```
                var params = new Array();
                $('ul li img.selected').each(function (index) {
                    params.push($(this).attr('id'));
                });

                var d = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format();

                var parameters = {
                    sessionHash: 'xxx',
                    start: d,
                    end: d,
                    artists: JSON.stringify(params)
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ws.asmx/GetDatesForArrayOfArtists",
                    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: (function Success(data, status) {
                        alert('hazzah!');
                    }),
                    error: (function Error(request, status, error) {
                        alert('poo botty bum smells');
                    })
                });
```

And this is my web service:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Calendar> GetDatesForArrayOfArtists(string sessionHash, DateTime start, DateTime end, int[] artists)
        {
            var u = UserObject.GetCurrentUser(sessionHash);

            //var ints = artists.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();

            return CalendarObject.GetDates(u.ClientId, start, end, artists);
        }
```

I've left some of my commented out code in, just so people can see my lame attempts at fixing this.  So, the basic question is, given the code above, how can I pass an array of integers to the web-service?

**EDIT 1:**  Here are two screenshots of the browsers console, this may go a way to explain the problem:

[image: post]
[image: response]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your trace `artists` is array of arrays of strings - `[["4","5"]]`. I think it should be `[4,5]` to work.

Consider changing adding parseInt to `params.push($(this).attr('id'));` and removing `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Having done this, I now get a `Type System.String is not supported for deserialization of an array."` error from the web service. Is this because I am now trying to deserialise an array of ints rather than strings?...Hmmm.... *investigative beavers*

Comment: I change the parameter on the webservice to `int[] artists` to accept the integers - which now look like this `[[3,4,5,6]]` and get a `"Type System.Int32 is not supported for deserialization of an array."` from the web service. I feel I'm going round and round in circles!

Comment: Ok, I got it to work! YEY!  Your answer sent me in the right direction, the integers needed parsing and I needed to remove the square brackets from the params within the `$.ajax` call, like this: `artists: params`.  It was ridiculously simple in the end. Thanks very much to all :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing line numbers etc. of the problem you are having, perhaps this might help:

If it doesn't could you please update your question with exactly where your code fails (which line and/or method).

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Calendar> GetDatesForArrayOfArtists(string sessionHash, 
                          DateTime start, 
                          DateTime end, 
                          string[] artists)
    {
        var u = UserObject.GetCurrentUser(sessionHash);

        return CalendarObject.GetDates(u.ClientId, 
                   start, 
                   end, 
                   artists.Select(artist => Integer.Parse(artist)).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Noting the horrendous lack of error checking and trust from the client (bad!)

Comment: Thanks for this Spence ;)  Unfortunately, this didn't solve the error.  I've edited the question with a little more detail as requested. Thanks for the help so far ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is:

In javascript build a new array:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray.push([value1, value2, ...]);
```

In C# just create a ICollection parameter to get your matrix:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void MyMethod GetMatrixFromJavascript(System.Collections.ICollection myArray) { 
    ...
}
```